# pserve starts and immediately stops with no warnings - how can I determine my mistake?

Tags: python, pyramid

Mac OS X Yosemite
Python 2.7.1 in a virtual env

If I run pserve, it starts, writes out a PID, then immediately stops with no warning and deletes the PID file.

If I turn on all the logging I just get warnings about pycountry.py.

Nothing else happens. My development.ini has not changed and it used to work.

Edit: I don't think those warnings have anything to do with it.

If I check dtruss -f -t pserver development.ini I get the errors:

```
dynamic variable drops with non-empty dirty list
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a test sample app to see if everything runs ok?. For example
     $VENV/bin/pcreate -s starter TestProject

Comment: The project is working in a linux environment. I've even verified that from a fresh Linux install, everything works as expected. There's something about the Mac environment. What I dont understand is why there are no errors at all.